# Google Analytics Event Tracking via a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

The proof of concept started with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.evnttrk1').click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'coming_soon', 'footer_icons', $(this).attr('id')]);
});
});
```

With this, any link with a class of eventrk1 would trigger a Google Analytics Event. This worked just fine.

From there I decide to roll it into a proper plugin, adding some functionality along the way. Everything about the plugin works *except* I can't get the _gaq.push to send events to Google. I'm not getting an error. I'm not getting anything at all.

I have the plugin running on this coming soon page: http://AcaciaNJ.com

I'd like to tell you this gave me gray hairs but that's not possible since it made me pull all my hair out. Please help. This is really starting to bother me.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try `window._gaq.push`?

You can detect if the `_gaq` object is available by testing for `window._gaq`:

```
if (window._gaq) {
    alert('_gaq found');
} else {
    alert('_gaq not found');
}
```

You could also pass an arbitrary function to `window._gaq.push()` to help with debugging:

```
window._gaq.push(function() {alert('Pushed function to _gaq')});
```

I also noticed that your script passes a fifth argument to `_trackEvent`, `val`. This has to be an integer, and tracking will not work if it is a string.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll try that. I'm a bit of a noob. Do you have a link that explains this tactic a bit more? I can do it. I just want to understand why. Also, if I do get found, or not found, for that matter. then what do I do?

Comment: These tips are just to try and find out why/where a problem is occurring - as you said you "not getting anything at all". Hopefully this may help explain why your ``_gaq.push`` line is not sending events.

Comment: First thing I'd try is removing the quotes from your ``val`` parameter:

    $('.etrk').ezeventtracking({etrk_def : {etrk_rig: 'able', etrk_tar: 'blank', etrk_cat: 'coming_soon', etrk_act: 'footer_icons', etrk_lab: 'useCSSid', etrk_val: 0}});

Comment: Thanks again Matt - 

1) I got "gaq found" so I presume that's good news.

2) I think your point about the value being an int and not a string is a very good one. I made that change. I'll wait to see if that change allows Google Analystic to get what it needs as it needs it. Could take 24+ hours. I'll be back either way.

You help and fresh eyes are greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Mark

Comment: Hey Matt! I think the value int / string issue did the trick. I'm getting results in GA. Thanks.

I'm going to give it another day or so before I declare victory but I can see visits (which never left) and I can see events. What a relief. Thanks again.