# Changing a string into an integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

This is a follow up question to this:

[Google Analytics Event Tracking via a jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845188/google-analytics-event-tracking-via-a-jquery-plugin)

Matt Austin was correct. I was passing a string of the integer for the GA value parm when I should have been passing the int value itself. Evidently Google Analytics is sensitive like that :)

So I changed: `parmValidatedObject[key] =  val;`

to: `parmValidatedObject[key] =  val.valueOf();`

But that doesn't seem to be working as expected. GA doesn't seem to pick this up as an int. What am I not understanding about `valueOf()`?

btw, I might also run into something similar with one of the other parms that's a boolean. I'm translating those strings to the value or 0 or 1 but I'm wondering (out loud and in advance) if that's the right approach.

Comment: Google parseInt - it's exactly what you need for this.

Comment: In addition to `parseInt` you could use the unary `+` operator if you wanted, i.e. `parmValidatedObject[key] = +val`.

Comment: thanks. let me give this a go and see if it helps. kinda sucks cause GA can take 24 hours to post new data. so it's change and wait. but this looks like a step in the right direction. i hope.

Answer (score 4):

`parseInt(val,10);` will convert your string to an integer. It is a JavaScript function, not jQuery.

`!!val` converts a value to a boolean. Note that `"0"` is considered a truthy value and so `!!"0"` returns `true`, unlike the `false` you might expect. In this case, you may be better off using
`(""+val == "0") ? false : true;`